# Kafka confluent proxy api - send message - Internal server error

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-requests, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I'm trying to wrap the Confluent kafka proxy api in one class that will handle producing and consuming.
Following this link: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html I tried to implement it as follows:

```
    def send(self, topic, data):
        try:
            r = requests.post(self._url('/topics/' + topic), json=data, headers=headers_v2)
            if not r.ok:
                raise Exception("Error: ", r.reason)
        except Exception as e:
            print(" ")
            print('Event streams send request failed')
            print(Exception, e)
            print(" ")
            return e
```

but I ended up working with 2 versions of the api (v2/v3) cause I didn't find some api's in one implementation and vise versa...
For example I didn't find how to create topic in v2, so I implemented it with v3.

My issue now is with the `send` method, I'm getting `Internal server error` and I can't find why!
Maybe because the create topic was done with v3 and I'm trying to produce messages with v2.

Comment: Do you need to use the proxy? Python has native producer/consumer libraries... You need to look at the server logs for internal errors

Comment: Yes proxy is needed. However, I managed as I wrote in my update. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the data payload for the send to look like:
`data = {"records": [{"value": data}]}` and send passed,

poll passed when using:
`r = requests.get(self._url('/consumers/' + self.consumer_group + '/instances/' + self.consumer + '/records'), headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json'})`